# why removing the first element in ArrayList is slow?

Tags: list, arraylist

some where I've read that removing the first element`arrayList.remove(0);` is slower than removing the last one `arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);` please some one provide the detailed explanation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Implementation of remove](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29):

```
public E More ...remove(int index) {
     rangeCheck(index);

     modCount++;
     E oldValue = elementData(index);

     int numMoved = size - index - 1;
     if (numMoved > 0)
         System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                          numMoved);
     elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

     return oldValue;
 }
```

The values are stored in an array, so if the last one is removed it only set the value in the array to null (elementData[--size] = null). But if it is somewhere else it needs to use arraycopy to move all the elements after it. So in the code above you can see clearly: **index = size - 1** implies the arraycopy call (the extra time used).

Answer (score 1):

In `ArrayList` the elements reside in contiguous memory locations.

So when you remove the first element, all elements from 2 to n have to be shifted.

E.g. If you remove 1 from [1,2,3,4], 2, 3 and 4 have to be shifted to left to maintain contiguous memory allocation.

This makes it a little slower.

On the other hand, if you remove the last element, there is no shifting required since all the remaining elements are in the proper place.